# How To Stop iText7 Image Cutoff When In A Table Cell

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7

I'm trying to use iText7 to create a PDF with questions that are stored in images and respective numbers. The numbers and the images must stay together on the same page, so I used a table object to keep them together; however, the images run off the edge of the page.

```
Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(8)).UseAllAvailableWidth();
Cell cellQuestionNumber = new Cell().Add(questionNum).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
Cell cellImage = new Cell().Add(img).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.AddCell(cellQuestionNumber);
table.AddCell(cellImage);
document.Add(table);
```

I've seen some people use `.SetAutoScaleWidth(true)` on the image, but when I do that the image just shrinks to an incredibly unreadable size.
[image: Here's the image without adding autoscale]. [image: Here's the image with autoscale].

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need in using tables here - you can add the elements you want to keep in one page into a `Div` and then use `setKeepTogether(true)` property to prevent splitting that `Div` over two pages.

To make sure an image does not occupy more than the width of the page you can set its maximum width property to 100%.

Here is a code example:

```
Image image = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create("C:\\Users\\Alexey\\Desktop\\Capture.PNG"));
Div div = new Div();
div.add(new Paragraph("#1.)"));
div.add(image.setMaxWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100)));
div.setKeepTogether(true);

document.add(div);
```